# Test perl sub without instantiating whole file

Tags: perl, object, testing, mocking

Given a perl file with something like this:

```
sub new {
    my $package = shift;

    my %params = @_;
    tons_of_other_initializers(%params);

}

sub simple_thing{

   print "hello";
}
```

How would I go about testing only simple_thing() without having to do all the initialization for the "object" ?

(The initialization includes a bunch of config files, setting up various data structures (that are mocked out for the test) and calls to external packages thus I really *really* don't want to run new)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how the subroutine works you might be able to get away with calling the method statically, such as:

```
use Your::Module::Here;

Your::Module::Here::simple_thing();
```

Or if you have dependencies on *$self* inject a dummy object which pretends its the object instance as the first argument in your static call (of course you'll have to sort out what it provides yourself).

```
use Your::Module::Here;
...
Your::Module::Here::simple_thing($mocked_self);
```

Alternative to the last example you could use a library like *Test::MockModule*

```
use Test::MockModule;
use Your::Module::Here;
...
my $mock = Test::MockModule->new('Your::Module::Here');
$mock->mock('new', sub { return $mocked_self; });
my $object = Your::Module::Here->new();
$object->simple_thing();
```